# Reading excel and set String value to Integer using Java POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I tried to read excel data using java poi and attempt to store in the database.

I read the values from the excel like

```
Integer.parseInt(formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(columnNum)))
```

in that, the excel may contain null values in the column. So It throws an **error**

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

when try to set excel values to Integer like

`riskVo.setProbability(Integer.parseInt(formatter.formatCellValue(row.getCell(columnNum))));`

**Note:** Probability is an Integer data type.

But It accepts the values if the column is not null.

This is the excel file.

[image]
The error occurs in 2nd row 2nd column which contains empty column.If the column has value it works perfectly.

Comment: Before parsing the data which you got from the cell, check if it's `NULL`, if yes don't parse. Parse it otherwise.

Comment: @Naveen are you expecting additional details in answer ?? if yes, then let us know, if no, then consider accepting and upvoting correct answer

Comment: @Naveen You are suppose to accept and upvote answer, please read this as what StackOverflow expects https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235

Comment: @Naveen I didn't forced you, looking at your rep, I thought you are new here, gave you reference. To know, how SO works. Also, if it didn't helped, then you are supposed to let poster know, what is missing. We are not here to work on your behalf instead help.

Comment: @Naveen SO is not only getting help, it is also to sharing help/knowledge. You simply posted your question and forgotten, imagine you or someone else faces same issue, then what would be the solution ???? It is your responsible to let poster know, what is missing and if you found solution then you are supposed to let everyone know by sharing/posting it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

Please note, there is difference between `""` and `NULL`. What you are getting exception is, because of empty string `""`, which is different than `NULL`.

For example :

```
String s  = "";
s.length ()// it will return 0
```

But,

```
String s  = null;
s.length ()// throw NPE.
```

So, you could probably first check, if `String` is not `null` and then check if it not empty.

```
if(str != null && !str.isEmpty()) {
```